# What does the notation f(·|θ) mean?

Tags: statistics, notation, stochastic-calculus

I've been trying to solve a sum where $X$ is a stochastic variable with density $f(\cdot | \theta)$ with density $f$ defined by:

$$f(x|\theta) = \frac{θ}{x^{\theta+1}} \tag{Pareto}$$

I don't really understand what $f(\cdot | \theta)$ means. Can anyone shed some light on this?

Comment: If denotes a PDF that is equipped with a parameter $\theta$. Its actual argument is $x$.

Comment: A family of probability densities parametrized by $\theta$ -- what is otherwise called *a statistical model*.

Comment: In general it is an placeholder for an argument of a function. With it you can express a function more generally.

Comment: It's sometimes written $f_\theta(x)$.

Comment: Look here:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mathematical_symbols_by_subject#Functions

Answer (score 0):

For simulation we have to specify the values of parameters; in such a context, the notation $f(x \mid \theta)$ suggests that $\theta$ (may be a vecotr) is "known". For statistical inference the values of parameters are to be investigated via data at hand; in this context, the notation $f(\theta \mid x)$ is preferable, which suggests that the "data" $x$ are known.

I think it will do no harm to read the bar "given".

Comment: "in this context, the notation f(θ∣x) is preferable" Sorry but no. For each fixed $θ$, $f(\cdot\mid θ)$ is a PDF. For each fixed $x$, $f(x\mid θ)$ is the *likelihood* of the sample $x$ for the PDF $f(\cdot\mid θ)$, thus one should rather use the notation $L(θ\mid x)=f(x\mid θ)$ or, even better, $L_x(θ)=f_θ(x)$.

Comment: @Did That is mathematically correct, for sure; but for statisticians that I know, they do not put so much emphasis on this distinction. It depends on the OP's background; here is no room for "true" or "false", I am afraid.